# How to add 'add to playlist' functionality in a songs list in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am extremely new to Angular and front-end development, and wondering how I can model/organize this feature. I am creating a very simple playlist/song site just to get my hands dirty.

I have a list of songs, and a list of playlists all with crud features. Playlist has many songs, but songs aren't connected to playlists. How can I add a way in the UI to add songs to playlists? Thinking of spotify there is a button on a song, where you can click 'add to playlist', and then all your playlists pop up in a little dropdown.

How can I model that in my Angular app? Do I create a new component with a view that simply does a  ng-for? But this seems redundant because I already have a playlist component that has a list of components. Is there a way I can render this component in a smaller dropdown?

Thanks

Comment: For my understanding: You display a list of songs and would like to have an "Add to playlist" button for each song in that list. And when you click that button you would like an overlay to open that shows all your playlists. Is that right?

Comment: Correct. After doing a bit more reading, it looks like ngrx state management might be a good way to do this? I.e. have a state called 'selected song'.. is that correct? Or are there better ways to do something like this?